# Send Broadcast notification using azure to IOS and android

Tags: c#, azure, notifications

IOS platform sends JSON payload in following format:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Notification Hub test notification"}}
```

whereas Android payload format is:

```
{"data":{"message":"Notification Hub test notification"}}
```

My `SendBroadcastNotification`:

```
public void SendBroadcastNotification(string message) {

    NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient
             .CreateClientFromConnectionString(Constants.NotificationsHubConnectionString, "QiKStayNotificationHub",true);
    var notify = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"" + message + "\"}}";
    var appnotify = "{ \"aps\" : {\"alert\":\"" + message + "\"}}";
    var task = hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notify);
    task.Wait();  
}
```

Since here I am sending notification to android SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync specifically I want to broadcast it to all devices.

So shall I change the payload JSON format likewise

```
hubClient.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync();
hubClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notify);
```

Comment: SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync will broadcast to all android device and SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync will broadcast to all apple device

Answer (score 0):

While registering device with notification hub you should maintain user's platform

```
 switch (platform.ToLower())
            {
                case "apns":
                    notificationMessage = "{ \"aps\" : {\"alert\":\"" + message + "\"}}";
                    break;
                case "gcm":
                    notificationMessage = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"" + message + "\",\"display\":\"" + title + "\"}}";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

or you can user template message

```
private static async void SendTemplateNotificationAsync()
{
    // Define the notification hub.
    NotificationHubClient hub = 
        NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
            "<connection string with full access>", "<hub name>");

    // Sending the notification as a template notification. All template registrations that contain 
    // "messageParam" or "News_<local selected>" and the proper tags will receive the notifications. 
    // This includes APNS, GCM, WNS, and MPNS template registrations.
    Dictionary<string, string> templateParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // Create an array of breaking news categories.
    var categories = new string[] { "World", "Politics", "Business", "Technology", "Science", "Sports"};
    var locales = new string[] { "English", "French", "Mandarin" };

    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        templateParams["messageParam"] = "Breaking " + category + " News!";

        // Sending localized News for each tag too...
        foreach( var locale in locales)
        {
            string key = "News_" + locale;

            // Your real localized news content would go here.
            templateParams[key] = "Breaking " + category + " News in " + locale + "!";
        }

        await hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(templateParams, category);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mahesh,I want to broadcast the notification so why do I need to check the pns tag Is there some other way wherein the json payload I could put some more tags ,likewise   "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"" + message + "\"}}" or  I have dynamic parameters that I can send var dynmicjson = "{'data':{'message':'$(message)','icon':'$(icon)',{$(params)}}}";

Comment: Hi Thanks! I almost applied same approach

 var users = ( from  u in db.Users select new
                {
                    u.Name
                }

                    );
              
                foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    var notify = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"" + message + "\", \"userId\":\"" + user.Name + "\"}}";
                    var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + message + "\"}}";

                    var task = hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notify);